# Difference from @event="doThis()" & @event="doThis" in Vuejs

Tags: vue.js

I've encountered this error

```
Cannot read property 'target' of undefined
```

with an `@click` event while calling a method with a `doThis()`.

But `doThis` worked fine

I would like to know what is the difference between

`<button type="button" @click="doThis()" data-name="test">Test</button>`

And

`<button type="button" @click="doThis" data-name="test">Test</button>`

with this method

```
methods: {
    doThis(e) {
      console.log(e.target.dataset.name);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the `e` which is the event object being handled is is undefined. You have to pass the object using global `$event`

```
<button type="button" @click="doThis($event)" data-name="test">Test</button>
```

Usually when you invoke the event handler manually is because you need to pass additional arguments to the function. As example

```
<div v-for="v in values" :key="v.id">
    <button type="button" @click="doThis($event, v)" data-name="test">Test</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As I was typing this up, @Chay22 was able to help - for what it's worth, here is an example:

[[CodePen Mirror]](https://codepen.io/oze4/pen/OYZxWZ)

```js
const vm = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    title: ''
  },
  methods: {
    doTheNeedful(e) {
      this.title = "Coming From: " + e.target.innerHTML;
      console.log(e);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div>
    <button @click="doTheNeedful">doTheNeedful</button>
    <button @click="doTheNeedful($event)">doTheNeedful($event)</button>
    <div v-if="title">
      <p>{{ title }}</p>
      <h3>Check console for event info</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```